# JAX-WS Schema Validation for nillable/required annotations

Tags: java, web-services, validation, jax-ws, xsd-validation

```
@XmlElement(required=true,nillable=false)
    private String address1;
```

I've annotated my class with nillable and required fields. However, when the user doesn't submit this field in the XML to the webservice there is no validation error.

Is there a way to enforce schema validation?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using JAX-WS RI, you can use this annotation:

```
@SchemaValidation
@WebService
public class MyServiceImpl {
}
```

However, it is not recommended to enable this feature in production due to high overhead. In production you can use a hardware validation solution (e.g. IBM XM70) or not validate at all if all your consumers are internal.